# ASP.Net Application won't start when I make a reference to a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on an ASP.Net application in Visual Studio and until yesterday everything worked fine. I just press the "Start in Google Chrome" button and it loads the page. But now all of a sudden it stopped working..

This is the way how it should be, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to access the methods I need:

```
public partial class InlogForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Webshop webshop;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webshop = new Webshop();
        }

        //rest of the class
    }
```

Yet it doesn't load in the browser until I comment out the field 'webshop'.

It has nothing to do with my hosts file, I already checked that and if it was caused by that, it wouldn't work if I comment out the field either.

Can somebody please help me, cause it's kind of important that I get it to work again, since it's for a school project

Comment: You might want to set webshop in a constructor.

Comment: would you please add a bit more code or be more specific what error you are getting...

Comment: But I'm not sure if the problem lies in  your code.

Comment: the page_load method functions the same as a form, since it's triggered at the loading of the page.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Are the `<customErrors>` set to Off (in web.config)?

Comment: I'm not getting any error... that's the problem... it's just showing that the page is loading, but the browser keeps its white background and it could go on for hours without any sign of progress

Comment: Put a breakpoint at that line and check what `new WebShop()` is doing.

Comment: okay now I get some sort of error:

Comment: Exception:Caught: "Access to path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\~AspAccessCheck_4201bb6e7652.tmp is denied." (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
A System.UnauthorizedAccessException was caught: "Access to path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\~AspAccessCheck_4201bb6e7652.tmp is denied."
Time: 3-6-2015 09:28:56
Thread:<No Name>[7652]

Comment: I solved it and came to a conclusion: no more late night programming for me... I made a console application to test the database connection and I had a readline in that, which I copied to this project and that was causing all this... thanks for the help anyway